# KeyDown preventing text appearing in TextBox [UWP]

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have the current UWP app targeting 10240:

```
<Page x:Class="App8.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
      <Grid>
           <ContentControl KeyDown="ContentControl_KeyDown">
              <TextBox  TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
           </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And:

```
namespace App8
{  
     public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
     {
            public MainPage() => InitializeComponent();
            private void ContentControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e) => e.Handled = true;
            private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) => Debug.WriteLine("NEVER RUNNING CODE");        
     }    
}
```

When I write  in the textbox I want to avoid any key events going to the main screen. In order to do that I have the KeyDown in the parent element of the textbox, and I handle the event. But If I do that the textbox doesn't write anything.

I'd like to end any key events going in the ContentControl going to the Page, but allowing the textbox to work normally. Any ideas?

Comment: What about adding a KeyDown Event handler to the textbox??

Comment: Already tried it, and doesn't work. It avoids the textbox from writing text.

Comment: This looks like a case for routing, bubbling and tunneling: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464926/To-bubble-or-tunnel-basic-WPF-events

Comment: Yes, the KeyDown event is going up before the TextChanged event, but I still want the textbox to work. and this is a UWP project so mouse preview and those events are not available.

Comment: Why would you not want any keys to be shown to the user?

Comment: In the keydown event you could modify the Text-Value of your textbox?

Comment: I have some doubts with your design, why you want to  handle the `KeyDown` in the `ContentControl` ? Is there some hotkey on your  main screen?

Comment: the textbox is in a popup, and I don't want keys strokes like up, left, down, up arrow traverse up to the parent, Because it triggers some events.

Comment: hi @etragu Does it work in your side?

Comment: I made a patch, but I don't thinkg the behavior of the textbox should rely on other UI elements handling keydown events

Comment: Could you share more about your patch?

Comment: I handle some specific keys I don't want to propagate Up in the UI tree, and when I detect those VirtualKeys I set e.Handled = true.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to end any key events going in the ContentControl going to the Page, but allowing the textbox to work normally. Any ideas?

For your requirement, you could make bool flag to tell main screen fire some events or not when the TextBox is focused or not.

```
private bool IsFocus;
private void MyTextBox_GettingFocus(UIElement sender, GettingFocusEventArgs args)
{
    IsFocus = true;
}

private void MyTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IsFocus = false;
}
```

**Usage**

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated;
}

private void Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher sender, Windows.UI.Core.AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
{
    if (IsFocus)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Do  Not Fire Your Event ");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" Fire Your Event ");
    }

}
```